# Dynamically override WooCommerce Stripe keys depending on products being ordered

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments, hook-woocommerce

I'm looking to extend the WooCommerce Stripe plugin so that it will dynamically change the Stripe keys, to pay into different stripe accounts depending on what product is being bought. It only needs to pay into one account at a time and there won't be any products for different stripe accounts in the same basket, so I'm hoping to get around it without having to use Stripe connect.

From what I can tell the connection between WooCommerce and Stripe is just based on having the secret/publishable keys on the store and the web hook setup on the stripe account, so to me it seems like it should simply be the case of changing the secret/publishable key dynamically at the point of checkout before the payment request is sent through to stripe. And as long as all of the stripe accounts have the web hook back to the store setup it should go through. 
But I may be wrong on it being this simple.

I can see from the Stripe documentation that the following filter hooks are available to use that hold the keys, so I imagine it can be hooked before the request is sent through to change these.

```
wc_stripe_params($params) // Localized JS key/value pair.

wc_stripe_payment_request_params($params) // Localized JS key/value pair.
```

I've asked WooCommerce for any further info on these parameters and how I can use them but I've been told it falls beyond the support they can provide.

Does anybody have any experience trying to do this with the WooCommerce stripe plugin and can point me in the right direction?

Any information would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am looking to implement something similar. Thanks.

Comment: @cwal Sorry, I didn't manage to solve this and have moved onto other projects. It is still in the background so if I get a chance to take a look over it again and find any solution I'll be sure to post it here.

Comment: ok no problem just figured I would ask in case! As it turns out, my client set up different bank accounts to different Stripe workspaces, but now that they have added their multiple bank accounts to the same workspace it solves my problem. However I do not think it solves your problem since I am dealing with currencies where you seem to be dealing with certain products going to different Stripe accounts. Thanks again!